# Error when using lambda function with Cython

Tags: python, cython

I am trying to use Cython to speed up a piece of code.  Cython is giving an error that reads "Expected an identifier or literal" when I use lambda functions.  As far as I can tell, lambda functions are meant to be supported in Cython 0.13.  Am I incorrect on this point?  If they are, indeed, supported, do I need to do something other than what I have here to implement them?

```
def f(e_1, e_2, rho):
    """Bivariate Normal pdf with mean zero, unit variances, and correlation coefficient rho."""
    return (1.0 / (2.0 * pi * sqrt(1 - rho**2))) * exp(-(1.0 / (2*(1 - rho**2))) * (e_1**2 + e_2**2 - 2*rho*e_1*e_2))

def P_zero(b_10, b_11, b_20, b_21, rho, gamma, x):
    """Returns the probability of observing zero entrants in a market by numerically
    integrating out the unobserved firm-specific profit shocks."""
    h_z = lambda e_1: -inf
    g_z = lambda e_1: -b_10 - b_11*x[0] - gamma*x[1]
    I   = lambda e_1, e_2: f(e_1, e_2, rho)
    return dblquad(I, -inf, (-b_20 - b_21*x[0] - gamma*x[2]), h_z, g_z)[0]
```

Comment: Exactly which line gives you the error?

Comment: I think you mean `I = lambda e1, e2: f(e1, e2, rho)`

Comment: Right, sorry.  The definition of h_z is drawing the error.

Comment: @razpeitia That was a typo.  It is fixed now.

Comment: `h_z = lambda e_1: -float('inf')`

Comment: does this work when you change the `foo = lambda ... `'s into `def foo():`'s?

Comment: @razpietia. You should definitely put that as an answer. It looks right to me. Disclaimer: I am not a Cython expert.

Comment: @razpeitia:  Thanks, but unfortunately I still get the same error.

Comment: Wait, Why are you using a function to return a constant value?

Comment: @razpeitia:  It seems scipy.integrate.dblquad requires this construction for the limits of integration of the first variable in the integrand, even if these limits are constant.  I should mention, however, that if I remove one of these lambda functions, the next one down also throws an error. So it seems to me that I am handling the lambda's incorrectly.

Comment: I always think it's a bit silly to give anonymous (lambda) functions names. The code won't run any faster than using regular function syntax. just use `def h_z(e_1):return -inf` etc. if for some good reason you don't want to spread it over two lines

Comment: @gnibbler:  I doo would prefer this.  However, Cython will not allow me to define functions inside other functions.  It says "def statement not allowed here."  Moreover, Cython will not let me move these inner functions outside of the function P_zere.  If I try it says that b_10, b_11, and gamma are "undeclared name not builtin."

Comment: @Randall, Ah yes, I'd forgotten about that. lambda is also trying to declare a function inside a function, this is also not permitted. The reason for the limitation may be something like cython not supporting closures etc. Whatever the reason, you will have to find a different way to approach your problem

Answer (score 2):

In my opinion you should change `h_z = lambda e_1: -inf` with `h_z = lambda e_1: -float('inf')` unless you have defined `inf` somewhere else.

Answer (score 0):

I'm able to compile the below simplified Cython code and run it fine using Cython 0.14.1 on OS X 10.6.6.  I don't know the details as to why it doesn't work on 0.13.  The easiest solution is to upgrade Cython, if possible.

```
def f(e_1, e_2, rho):
    return e_1 + e_2 + rho

def dummy(a, b, c, d, e):
    return [a(1,2) + b + c + d(1) + e(3)]

def P_zero(b_10, b_11, b_20, b_21, rho, gamma, x):
    h_z = lambda e_1: -1000
    g_z = lambda e_1: -b_10 - b_11 * x[0] - gamma * x[1]
    I   = lambda e_1, e_2: f(e_1, e_2, rho)
    return dummy(I, -1000, (-b_20 - b_21 * x[0] - gamma * x[2]), h_z, g_z)[0]

print P_zero(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, [6, 7, 8]) 
# outputs "-2122"
```